# How to Redirect from One URL to Another Showing the New URL

Tags: domain-name-system, redirection

I have an old domain `www.olddomain.com`, and now I have shifted my content to `www.newdomain.com`. Both of the domains are residing in the same root folder on a sharehost.

I use CPanel to manage them.

Now, when the user types in `www.olddomain.com`, I want it to be redirected to `www.newdomain.com`, with the address bar showing `www.olddomain.com`.  How can this be accomplished?

I tried to use "redirects" feature in Domains list, and although I could get the redirection, but the address bar showed `www.newdomain.com`, not `www.olddomain.com`.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you would need to setup a [CNAME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNAME_record) for www.olddomain.com to make it an alias for www.newdomain.com. This help file from Google Apps has information about setting up [CNames on popular domain registrars](http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=47283).

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove any redirects use cPanel's parked domains feature:
http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/CpanelDocs/ParkedDomains

Alternatively, you can use Greg's answer, but that's assuming you are on a dedicated IP or you have a vhost entry setup (parked domains do this for you) for olddomain.com